# Usage of "later on"

Tags: word-usage

Can I use *later on* on the following sentence?

> I'll check the website later on.
>   I'll inform you later on.

Please correct me for any mistake and let me know the best fix for it.

Comment: **later on** is a phrase, it is used to talk about a time in the future. It's used as an adverbial. Yes, in your sentence you can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "later on" is used colloquially in American English.  The "on" is unnecessary, however.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! While I think your answer is correct, I think it could be made better by adding a little more explanation or an example.

Comment: @RSQ, then "I'll check the website later" is a correct form?

Comment: @ColleenV, what should I add? can you please give me an example?

Comment: A little more explanation of the "on" being unnecessary, like explaining that "I'll check later on." means the same thing as "I'll check later." with some examples or references. Looking at some references, it seems like "later on" is used to mean subsequently or afterward, while later can just mean "at some time in the future".